# MAC to IP binding in ASA 5510 / SG 300-52

Tags: cisco, ip, mac, cisco-asa, local-area-network

I am trying to configure a Cisco ASA 5510 to assign specific IP-addresses to specific MACs. Firmware on my ASA is 8.2(5). I have used this feature in our previous device (Cisco SA-520W). I have also read that this feature is (not yet) implemented. How do I work around this problem, if not by direct assignment? Do I need to specify fixed IP's on concerned devices themselves?

I also have a SG 300-52 switch for our LAN. We cannot specify IP-addresses to ports, because we have further switches down the line.

Comment: Do you have another device that you could run DHCP on, like a server?

Comment: We have a server running Windows Server 2008. We can also make a dedicated DHCP out of a desktop computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is probably to run DHCP on the Windows server, since it'll have the needed DHCP reservation capability.

If the server is in a different broadcast domain as the one you're providing addresses for, you'll need to have the ASA act as a DHCP relay - that's configured with the `dhcprelay enable` and `dhcprelay server` commands.